# Armature deform on same placed verticies of different objects creates weird gaps

Tags: armature, vertices, pose-mode

I am using different objects that got vertices with shared location. However, it seems like there are gaps in between the objects though I made sure they are all from the same location. Is there a way to make those behave the same and the rest of the objects keep their specific deformation? (-> so they behave as if they were in the same object and the doubles got removed)
Thanks for helping.
Picture:
[image: mouth area should not be intersected, the seams should behave as same object]

Comment: Would you be able to post a picture? The problem will be easier to see and maybe someone can spot something you missed.

Comment: Did so. Hope this makes easier to see what I mean.

Comment: I can see the issue. If this is a rigged model, check that the vertices in the area in question are deformed by the same bone with the same influence. If that doesn't work, I would need to look at the model

Comment: It are two different objects. I will try to make the influence the same.

Comment: If that doesn't work. Post a link to the file

Comment: The file is too large, I always got trouble uploading it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75366/discussion-between-vectorius-and-xdonnervogelx).

Answer (score 1):

If two meshes have no unapplied scale/rotation/location, any vertices in the exact same locations, with the exact same weights, will be deformed in the exact same way by two identical armature modifiers.  (Same armature, same deformation mode-- "preserve volume".)

To make sure that vertices are in the *exact* same location, you can always shrinkwrap to the nearest vertex and apply.  To make sure that vertices have the *exact* same weights, you can data transfer from nearest vertex and apply.

To see the specific weights of a vertex, select that vertex in edit or weight paint mode and look on the sidebar, item tab, vertex groups section.

To make sure that meshes are using the exact same armature modifier, you can copy modifiers from the link menu (ctrl-L for me.)

Note that modifiers evaluated before the armature can change the position and/or weights of verts.  What matters are the values at the time that the armature modifier is evaluated.

As an aside specific to this picture, I've found that a surface deform is a much easier way to deform mouth interiors.  Because of differences in topology, you can get clipping (not from the margin verts, not if you're careful about weights and positions) from just an armature modifier.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done if both objects have the armature modifier, and are parented to the same armature.

The vertices that meet must have the same influences and only 1 bone affecting both areas.

Comment: Is there any way to find out the amount of weight (the exact one) a verticy does have in weight paint mode? I am currently trying to find any sort of weight color picker or anything or to read it some way but I don't find anything.

Comment: Since you are having issues with Rigify and weight paint, I would recommend [DanPro's Youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLizSCQYO0I6OgkNrDXuoRR0_ebpHWkj7w). They are for an older version of rigify, but most things still apply.

Comment: @xDonnervogelx https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156882/is-it-possible-to-see-vertex-weights-in-edit-mode-in-the-3d-view shows where to view individual vertex weights.