# Is it possible to see Vertex Weights in Edit Mode in the 3D View?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

Is [this documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/vertex_weights.html#display-weights-in-edit-mode) simply out of date? Is it possible to manipulate vertex weights in Edit Mode in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have the exact same thing in 2.8, but to see the weight for the selected vertex you first need to assign it some weight, either in *Weight Paint* mode or with the *Assign* button under the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *Vertex Groups* list. As Robin says: The panel is displayed only when you have a vertex which has been assigned to a vertex group selected, even with a 0 weight value.

[image]

To see both the wireframe and the weight you can enable *Vertex Group Weights* in the *Viewport Overlays*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Maybe this comment can supplement your answer with the detail that had me goofed. The panel is displayed _only when you have a vertex which has been assigned to a vertex group selected_. The difference between 'assigned to group x with value 0' and 'not assigned to group x' is not always clear: they're both blue in the painting system. The distinction isn't very consistent with Bevel Weight, etc.. I can't see a motive for it, except to save storage/lookup... but you could get around those, internally. I don't remember this in 3DS, XSI, etc..

Comment: Yes it makes no sense to me... Also note that, in the Viewport Overlays again, if you enable the Zero Weight > Active option under the Vertex Group Weights option, it displays black when the weight is 0, which should be the display setting by default.

Comment: Ahhh! More is revealed! At least you can tell them apart now. I guess (naturally) the system is geared to bone deformations, trying to avoid massive lists of groups appearing in the UI, which a vertex has nothing to do with. If I'm working on the left hand, I don't want to know (this vertex) is **not** weighted by the right ankle-bone.. but I still think there are better ways,,

Comment: A solution could be that when you select a vertex that is not affected to any group it would however be displayed in the panel, with the last selected vertex group displayed in grey (on the left of its weight value). Also as I said it would be logical that when you choose to display the Weight the black would be displayed by default, the question is often asked why it is blue yet it is part of a group. I don't know if there's any reason for these 2 solutions not to be implemented.

Comment: It's gratifying, though, how often I've thought 'This could be better' ... and then later, Blender has turned out to be right. Keeping a UI **minimal**, as well as complete, is a tough job, and expects the user to acquire some skills. The user is still the most sophisticated machine at the desk, after all. IMO, a lot of commercial packages fail at this .. 3DS, Photoshop..

Comment: mmh yes but sometimes I think we are right   ;)   Blender is so big that the Blender developers can't take care of everything, plus when you're used to a tool you sometimes lose sight of the obvious... it might also be some coding difficulties...