# Viewing weight data in edit mode

Tags: weight-painting

I'm trying to follow a rigging tutorial done in an older version of blender and, while in edit mode, the guy clicks on an option to display weight data in the 3d viewer. I cannot find this option anywhere in 2.8. Has this changed?

Thanks,
Rusty

Comment: It is confusing at first, but there are good reasons for the way it's done: see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156889/35559).. and be aware of the difference between a vertex in a group with weight 0, and a vertex not in the group at all.

Comment: Thanks Robin. This helped clarify something for me. It wasn't clear to me until now that only one vertex must be selected at a time in order to see the Vertex Weight panel. I had been frustrated in the past because, sometimes the panel would show and other times it wouldn't, and I didn't know why. Now I know that even if you're in Edit Mode, and even if you are selecting vertices that are in vertex groups, you still won't see the Vertex Weights panel in the Properties Shelf unless only one vertex is selected.