# Rigify. vertex weight 1 to one bone but something else still influencing!

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify, vertex-weights

I tried Rigify and I found a very strange issue. After I painted full chest bone weight on body vertices, they are still affected by the neck bone somehow.  I googled hard but it looks like nobody has a same problem like I have.

Would you like to help me to figure it out please?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KwnOk5825HrOVAxbsHc8u-_rvUQxoFQ_/view?usp=sharing

Neck joint:

[image: Neck joint]

Comment: Hello, I saw the animation, but I couldn't reproduce it. Could you share reproducible files.

Comment: You can check the weights of the vertices. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156882/is-it-possible-to-see-vertex-weights-in-edit-mode-in-the-3d-view

Comment: Thank you for your help. I checked the article you introduced and it was very useful. Unfortunately, the weights on the list were all fine. Also, I'm terribly sorry that I accidentally uploaded different file. Now, the download link is fixed and I triple checked. Sorry again.

Comment: By displaying **B-Bone** it can be seen that _DEF-spine.003_ is deformed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought something must influencing on it but I couldn't find it. Now, I need to figure out how to stop using b-bone but this is such a great clue to start from. Thank you again!

Comment: Already fixed! I set the segments value 0. Amazing!

Comment: If you found a solution, please write an answer in the answers section, so that others with similar issues can learn from your experience.