# Avatar's skin stretches when moving the armature in pose mode

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I've finished rigging an avatar and, as the title suggests, whenever I try to move the armature in pose mode, the avatar's mesh from the feet and hands stay in place, stretching out the skin.

[image: Screenshot showing skin stretching#1]

[image: Screenshot showing skin stretching#2]

I think it might have something to do with the control bones since when I move the bones and control bones too far away from each other,  Any tips would be great!

Comment: Just a guess: You have forgotten to disable the [Deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/properties/deform.html) option for your control bones and made them deform bones. If yes, then uncheck the option and delete the vertex groups with the same name as the control bones.

Comment: @Blunder So I've un-deformed the control bones, and it worked fine for the hands. The feet, not so much. Not sure what a vertex group is, though. Where can I find it?

Comment: The vertex groups are in the *Properties panel > Object Data Properties tab* (right side on the screen below the outliner) => https://i.stack.imgur.com/veXQe.png -- If you don't know which bone is the bad one you also can check the weights in the *Edit* mode. The weights are displayed in the viewport's side panel (key N to open it). Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/156882/107598