# Problem to close the eyes with Rigify

Tags: rigging, rigify

I use Rigify to rig one of my head, but when I close the eyes, there are some faces who don't follow so it makes a hole.
I think the problem comes from the weight painting, however, I don't really understand how it works.
Here is a screenshot to show you the problem : [image: eyes problem]

And here is the link to the .blend if anyone wants to try something: https://mega.nz/file/kGBEnQgZ#2CSlEXGt2Vr67HapsBl3P8dWFIYWwS2ATdN7u6uTGaM

Thank in advance!
Have a good day!

Comment: There is a gap because the vertices are affected by the top lid bone and the lower eyebrow bone. You need to fix the weights manually. In *Edit* mode you can check the weights with the Vertex Groups Weights (VGW) overlay. Enable it and select a vertex. Then you can see the weights and in the side panel, you can see the numbers of the weights. Clicking on a VG name switches to the group and you can see the weights. Here is a similar question & example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/211089/107598 and here is the VGW overlay: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/156882/107598

Comment: By the way, there is something wrong with the generated rig. The top left controller bone is called just *Bone* for some reason and has the wrong shape. If you want to start over with a fresh meta rig to fix this issue you can use this script to copy the bone layout from your edited meta rig: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194425/107598. Consider adding a head and a neck bone so you can move the head. It also helps with the calculation of the auto weights and the top of the head doesn't move when you make a blink animation.